# Clase de caracteres para cualquier letra, incluyendo todo tipo de acentos

Tags: regex, lenguaje-agnóstico

Encontré una expresión regular que sirve para un caso en particular: un input que pueda recibir todo tipo de acentos y también guión medio, e impide cualquier otro signo dentro del input.

Sin embargo, no entiendo mucho por qué está definida así. No quiero copiar y pegar algo que no entiendo por qué me sirve. No sé si aplica a una pregunta, pero de todas formas la formulo.

```
/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+$/
```

Comment: Ojo que no incluye al guión medio. Si quisieras incluirlo, deberías agregar a `\-` dentro de los corchetes. `/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+$/.test("ab-cd")` devuelve `false`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La expresión regular: `/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+$/` está compuesta de lo siguiente:

```
/ indica el inicio y fin de la expresión regular
^ inicio del string
$ fin del string   
[xyz] denota un conjunto de caracteres
a-z caracteres entre la a minuscula y la z minuscula charcode 97 al 
122
A-Z caracteres entre la A mayúscula y la Z mayúsucla charcode 65 al 90
À-Ö charcode 192 al 214
Ø-ö charcode 216 al 246
ø-ÿ charcode 248 al 255
+ una o mas caracteres
```

es decir la expresión regular concuerda con cualquier string que tenga los caracteres entre los corchetes [] y que tenga longitud 1 o superior.

La expresión regular usa como base los caracteres ascii https://www.ascii-code.com/

además te recomiendo usar : https://regexr.com/ o https://regex101.com/ para evaluar tus expresiones

Comment: Gracias a ambos, me quedo muy clara la explicación!

Comment: Con gusto @sioesi, que bueno poder ayudar =)

Answer (score 4):

Complementando [la respuesta de FelipeM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/117560/127), la [clase de caracteres](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set) `[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]` coincide con 1 caracter, cualquiera dentro de esos 5 rangos.

Y esos 5 rangos, cubren todas las letras (alfabéticas) de los 2 [bloques Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block) más usados:

- [Latino Básico](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/basic_latin/list.htm) (`\u0000` a `\u007F`), y
- [Latino-1 Suplementario](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/list.htm) (`\u0080` a `\u00FF`).

`A-Z` y `a-z` en el bloque Latino Básico: <sup>**[1](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0020-007F)**</sup>

[image: Caracteres de la A a la Z en mayúsculas y minúsculas, mostrando los símbolos que quedan excluidos del 0 al 127]

<sup>* No se muestran los caracteres del \u0000 al \u001F ([códigos de control C0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes)), que no son imprimibles.</sup>
<sup>* No se muestran los caracteres del \u0080 al \u009F ([códigos de control C1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes)), que tampoco son imprimibles.</sup>

`À-Ö`, `Ø-ö` y `ø-ÿ` en el bloque Latino-1 Suplementario: <sup>**[2](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/00A0-00FF)**</sup>

[image: Caracteres alfabéticos del bloque Latino-1 Suplementario, mostrando los símbolos que quedan excluidos del 128 al 255]

O sea, `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ`.

---

Notas:

- No se incluye al guión medio (`-`). Los guiones en la clase de caracteres sólo construyen rangos. Si quisieras incluirlo, deberías agregarlo escapado como `\-` dentro de los corchetes.
  <sub>- Otra opción es agregar el guión, sin escaparlo, al inicio o al final de la clase, donde nunca forman un rango.</sub>
- Tampoco se incluyen espacios ni otros signos de puntuación.
- No incluye a *todas* las letras latinas con diacríticos. Algunos caracteres muy poco frecuentes de los bloques [Latino Extendido-A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_extended_a/list.htm) (`\u0100` a `\u017F`) o [Latino Extendido-B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_extended_b/list.htm) (`\u0180` a `\u024F`) no están en la clase.

  [image: Caracteres del Bloque Latino Extendido-A no incluidos]
  [image: Caracteres del Bloque Latino Extendido-B no incluidos]

  Ejemplos: [`ĩ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0129/index.htm), [`Ō`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/014c/index.htm), [`ũ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0169/index.htm), [`ŷ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0177/index.htm), [`ƒ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0192/index.htm), [`ǎ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01ce/index.htm), [`ȩ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0229/index.htm), [`Ɇ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0246/index.htm), etc.
- Obviamente, tampoco se incluyen letras del [Bloque Latino Extendido Adicional](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_extended_additional/list.htm), ni de los alfabetos [griego](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/greek_and_coptic/list.htm), [cirílico](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/cyrillic/list.htm), [armenio](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/armenian/list.htm), [hebreo](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/hebrew/list.htm) o [arábico](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/arabic/list.htm), entre [muchos otros](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm).
- La página [*Match Unicode Block Range*](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) genera una clase de caracteres a partir de los bloques Unicode que se seleccionen.
- Si sólo se quieren letras del español, la clase es `[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚÜÑáéíóúüñ]` o, lo que es lo mismo, ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas:

  ```
  /^[a-záéíóúüñ]+$/i
  ```
- Si bien no hay otra forma en JavaScript (que tiene la peor implementación de expresiones regulares), otros lenguajes permiten formas más amigables de coincidir con letras.

Comment: He aprendido mucho con tu explicación @Mariano, muchas gracias =)

Comment: @FelipeM somos dos felipe, gracias a ambos

Answer (score 2):

En cómputo teórico y teoría de lenguajes formales una expresión regular, también conocida como regex, regexp1​ o expresión racional,2​3​ es una secuencia de caracteres que forma un patrón de búsqueda, principalmente utilizada para la búsqueda de patrones de cadenas de caracteres u operaciones de sustituciones.

En tu ejemplo:

```
\       Buscará coincidencias
^       Coincide con el principio de la entrada
$       Busca el final de la entrada
+       Busca el carácter precedente 1 o más veces
[xyz]   Grupo de caracteres
```

Comment: Gracias, entiendo bien lo que me explicas, pero me queda la duda `a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ` porque se permite todos los acentos con esos caracteres. Esas O con esos acentos extraños,entiendo que `À` acepta vocales con acentos o me equivoco? eso es lo que busco entender, el grupo de caracteres

Comment: a-z representa cualquier caracter entre la a y la z incluyendo la a y la z. Es decir representa rangos de caracteres. A-Z lo mismo con las mayúsculas. Y lo mismo aplica a esos otros caracteres acentuados.