# ¿Cómo se agregan símbolos como +, *,,/, etc, a la definición de una expresión regular?

Tags: java, regex, compilador, ascii

Estoy tratando de hacer un analizador léxico para cuestiones escolares, el punto es que los comentarios se deben iniciar con doble barra "//" y después de ellas puede haber caracteres de cualquier tipo, ya sea signos de exclamación e interrogación, símbolos aritméticos, espacios o caracteres especiales. Sin embargo, para la definición de las expresiones regulares estos símbolos son utilizados.
La expresión regular que por el momento tengo es:

```
[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ_0-9 \n\t\r,.;]+
```

Parte de esta expresión regular la tomé de la respuesta que está en el siguiente [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117556/clase-de-caracteres-para-cualquier-letra-incluyendo-todo-tipo-de-acentos).
Con la expresión regular como la tengo hasta el momento acepta cadenas como:

```
//Hola, que tal;
//Hola.;,ooo
//
//1234
```

Los comentarios que no acepta son, por ejemplo:

```
//Hola--------
//Comentario+-+-*
//Hola/+
```

Aunque el resultado es aceptable para comentarios pequeños hay ocasiones en que se desea dibujar una matriz o un arreglo con caracteres, cosa para lo cual no sirve esta expresión regular.

Comment: ¿podrías poner un ejemplo de comentario que no funcionase bien?

Comment: Los caracteres espaciales deben escaparse con una contra barra `\`. Por ejemplo `\+` y `\*`. Pero quizá tu expresión regular se simplifique con la concordancia de cualquier carácter (`.`) hasta el final de línea (`$`): `//.*$`. Si nos proporcionas el código y algún ejemplo podremos mostrarte cómo hacerlo mejor.

Comment: Tal y como lo mencionas hacía falta ponerlos con una contra barra, ha quedado solucionado el problema. La expresión regular ha quedado algo grande, traté de hacerlo simplificado como dices pero no me ha resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que recomiendo es separar en partes lo que quieres analizar, por ejemplo, si tu contexto es analizar codigo java, lo que puedes hacer es tener un regex para encontrar solo comentarios:

```
[\/]{2,}[\s\S]+
```

Lo que hace esta expresion es encontrar cualquier caracter `/` con 2 o mas repeticiones, escapado con `\`, ya que el caracter `/` es reservado para la sintaxis regex. En la siguiente seccion le decimos que encuentre cualquier caracter que sea un espacio en blanco `\s` y cualquier caracter que no sea un espacio en blanco `\S` con 0 o mas repeticiones.

Con esta otra puedes comparar sintaxis del inicio de clase en Java:

```
[\s]+public[\s]+class... bla bla
```

Donde indicamos que debe haber cualquier espacio en blanco con 0 o mas repeticiones luego la palabra `public`, de nuevo cualquier espacio en blanco con 0 o mas repeticiones y asi sucesivamente.

No te esfuerzes en hacer todo con una expresion, trata de separar cada linea por vez, sino quedara muy pesada y el compilador, en el lenguaje que utilices, podria tomar mucho tiempo en tratar de generar el bytecode para esta expresion.

Otra recomendacion que puedo hacer es que utilizes herramientas online para hacer pruebas rapidas, existen otras expresiones mas complejas que solo es posible hacerla mediante el compilador, pero en general estas herramientas online siempre cubren la mayoria.

Referencia: [Online Tool](https://regexr.com/)